# PostgreSQL ALTER TABLE takes 35 minutes

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN category_id integer
```

I've executed this query on production with load on the server. It took 35 minutes according to the datadog.

this `table1` has around 100 million rows.

Is 35 minutes normal? Is there any way I can execute such simple migrations (adding a nullable column) without locking the table?

Comment: I do not feel 35 is abnormal. I am just curious about why you want to alter a table without locking it? Are you making migration while people are connected and using the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will only take a split second.

You must have spent 35 minutes waitung for the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table to be granted (all the while blocking any transaction unfortunate enough to be queued behind you).

You probably have a problem with long transactions. Normally they should be as short as possible, otherwise they hold locks for a long time and also keep `VACUUM` from cleaning up dead row versions.

The lock is necessary, but is should not pose a problem with a well behaved database workload.

Comment: I think this is the answer thanks, is there any way I can alter table without `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE`? I don't care about consistency for a few minutes since it's a nullable field anyway. so I'm okay if a client gets half of the rows with that nullable field and half not.

or databases are too consistent for this kind of, batched modification operations?

any insights or tutorials about this issue? thanks!

Comment: There is no way to do this. Database metadata cannot change in mid-query. Just keep your transactions short. Long transactions are almost always a bug, either a design bug or an implementation bug.